# Use CoffeeScript class in AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, class, coffeescript

I have a presenter class written in a CoffeeScript. It's in a file which is loaded before AngularJS controller. But I can't use this class there. How could I use it?

presenter:

```
class CompanyPresenter
  constructor: (company) ->
    @company = company

  location: ->
    if @company.business.city && @company.country_id
      @company.business.city + ', ' + @company.country_id
    else if @company.business.city
      @company.business.city
    else if @company.country_id
      @company.country_id
    else
      undefined
```

controller:

```
@Sim.controller 'CompanyShowCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams',
   'language'
  ($scope, $http, $stateParams, language) ->

    $http.get('businesses/' + $stateParams.id).success((businessAttributes) ->
      $scope.business = businessAttributes
      # this doesn't work :(
      $scope.businessPresenter = new CompanyPresenter($scope.business)
    )
```

I tried to avoid using `service` or `factory`, because I don't need singleton, I want to initialize it with my model and be able to reuse it.

Comment: Post the solution as an answer instead of into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I added this line after class definition

```
@Sim.value('CompanyPresenter', CompanyPresenter)
```

and injected `'CompanyPresenter'` to the `CompanyShowCtrl`.